# Почему происходит ошибка компиляции?

Tags: typescript

Создаем объект внутри класса:

```
class AppComponent {

dish = {};

loadDishWindow(){
    console.log(this.dish);
    //->Object {}

    this.dish = {
        attributes : [],
        id : null ,
        name : "",
        type : null,
        type_id: null,
        unit: null,
        unit_id: null
    };

    console.log(this.dish);
    //->Object {attributes: Array[0], id: null, name: "", type: null, type_id: null…}

}
```

Почему, если я произведу вызов `console.log(this.dish.name);` в этом методе, вместо последнего `console.log()`, например, то при компиляции выдает ошибку?

```
error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Пользуюсь gulp'ом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### почему:

```
let dish = {};
console.log(dish.name);// ошибка, у блюда отсутствует имя
// в общем(но не конкретном) случае решается интерфейсами
// https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html
```

(привет статическая типизация)

```
let число = 78;
число = 'строка';// ошибка, тип число не может принять тип "строка"
```

### решение:

```
class AppComponent {
// предпочтительней так
dish = <any>{};
// но можно и так
// dish; //в скомпилированном коде он тут не создаётся(см. js)



// или как-то так
interface idish {
    attributes : string[],
    id         : null | number ,
    name       : null | string,
    type       : null | string,
    type_id    : null | string,
    unit       : null | any,
    unit_id    : null | any,
};
class AppComponent {
    dish:idish = <any>{}
}
```

---

upd:
по поводу **null** и **undefined**
интересно пишут [здесь](http://frontender.info/exploring-the-abyss-of-null-and-undefined-in-javascript/)
своё имхо озвучено [тут](https://github.com/FrontenderMagazine/exploring-the-abyss-of-null-and-undefined-in-javascript/issues/1#issuecomment-266958072)